# How to set TypeScript function parameter type to return type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, types, zustand

I am defining a zustand store (library irrelevant for this question) and would like to avoid maintaining a separate type or interface for that store, so I'm trying to infer it from the return type of my initial store:

```
export const useStore = create<ReturnType<typeof getInitialStore>>(
  withImmer((set, get) => getInitialStore(set, get))
)
```

As you can see, I want to set the type of the store to the initial store (see below), instead of `create<Store>`, which forces me to add each new field to the initial store as well as to the `Store` type.

This is the function I want to infer the type from, but the problem is that it takes two parameters that also depend on its return type:

```
const getInitialStore = (
  set: CustomSetState<ReturnType<typeof getInitialStore>>,
  get: GetState<ReturnType<typeof getInitialStore>>
) => {
  // ...
  return { my, store, fields }
}
```

TS doesn't let me do this and gives me this error:
`'getInitialStore' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.`

Is there a way to achieve this without a separately maintained `Store` type?

Comment: `getInitialStore` has not type defined, hence it's set to `any`

Comment: What do you mean by "separately" maintained type? Separate from what? Do you just mean you don't want to define a type for your store?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to avoid having a type defined because in theory it can be inferred perfectly from what I return from the `getInitialStore` function

Comment: The problem is the inherently circular nature of this setup, ie "This is the function I want to infer the type from, but the problem is that it takes two parameters that also depend on its return type"  I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Right, I wasn't considering that the return type could depend on these parameters since in my case I wasn't using them (yet), but now it makes sense. Thanks.